# Python: replace an exact matching substring with variable

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of strings like `'cdbbdbda', 'fgfghjkbd', 'cdbbd'` etc. I have also a variable fed from another list of strings. What I need is to replace a substring in the first list's strings, say `b` by `z`, only if it is preceeded by a substring from the variable list, all the other occurrences being intouched.
What I have:

```
a = ['cdbbdbda', 'fgfghjkbd', 'cdbbd']
c = ['d', 'f', 'l']
```

What I do:

```
for i in a:
    for j in c:
        if j+'b' in i:
            i = re.sub('b', 'z', i)
```

What I need:

```
'cdzbdzda'
'fgfghjkbd'
'cdzbd'
```

What I get:

```
'cdzzdzda'
'fgfghjkbd'
'cdzzd'
```

all instances of 'b' are replaced.
I'm new in it, any help is very welcome. Looking for answer at Stackoverflow I have found many solutions with regex based on word boundaries or with `re` either with `str.replace` based on `count`, but I can't use it as the lenght of the string and number of occurrences of 'b' can vary.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you include `j` in the find and replace, you'll get what you want.

```
>>> for i in a:
...     for j in c:
...         i = re.sub(j+'b', j+'z', i)
...     print i
... 
cdzbdzda
fgfghjkbd
cdzbd
>>>
```

I added `print i` because your loop doesn't make in-place changes, so without that output, it's not possible to see what replacements were made.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use regular expressions with a positive lookbehind assertion.

Like this:

```
import re

for i in a:
  for j in c:
    i = re.sub('(?<=' + j + ')b', 'z', i)
```

The base case is:

```
re.sub('(?<=d)b', 'z', 'cdbbdbda')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
import re
a = ['cdbbdbda', 'fgfghjkbd', 'cdbbd']
c = ['d', 'f', 'l']
new_a = [re.sub('|'.join('(?<={})b'.format(i) for i in c), 'z', b) for b in a]
```

Output:

```
['cdzbdzda', 'fgfghjkbd', 'cdzbd']
```